# What does "if" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The outlay on the Real Madrid winger may yet prove to be too much, too late, **if**
>   United’s Capital One Cup capitulation at the hands of MK Dons offers a true
>   barometer of the current state of health at Old Trafford.

The "if clause" here as conditional clause doesn't make sense to me. And I think "if" doesn't mean "whether" either.

Answer (score 3):

It's a conditional. You can read the sentence as a conditional clause by moving the "if" first.

> **If** United’s Capital One Cup capitulation at the hands of MK Dons offers a true barometer of the current state of health at Old Trafford, **[then]** the outlay on the Real Madrid winger may yet prove to be too much, too late.

Taking some liberties and paraphrasing out the football terms:

> **If** you think the team's recent bad performance is indicative of their future performance, **then** the price was too high to pay for that new player.

In other words, the author is trying to convince you to conclude something like:

> The team paid too much for the new player.

This is confirmed if we look at [the article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/manchester-united/11058490/Manchester-United-turmoil-is-partly-down-to-Sir-Alex-Ferguson-and-the-clubs-transfer-policy.html) your quote comes from. We can see that the author concludes the article with:

> The 'value in the market' policy has failed and it is United who are now embarking on 'kamikaze' spending.